# where is it mentioned in manga of MHA that Deku's father has fire breathing quirk?

Tags: my-hero-academia

I only found on [fandom source](https://myheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/Hisashi_Midoriya) and I have not read the manga, so what is the main source where it is mentioned that Deku's father has Unnamed Fire Breath Quirk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the very first volume, when his mother takes him to the doctor, and the doctor asks if she and his father have quirks, she states that she can pull small objects toward her, and

> my husband can breathe fire.